# How to use an Apex Email Service to store emails on a record EXACTLY as Salesforce does?

Tags: apex, lightning-experience, tasks, apex-email-service, emailmessage

I have used the Lightning Experience UI to send an Email from a Record Homepage via Activity-Tab. This looks like this (bottom-right!):

[image]

Now I want (vice versa) to store an incoming email received by an Apex Email Service in exactly the manner as Salesforce is doing that for outbound emails. At least I want to push I as close as possible or practical.

**Note: I want that fancy stuff, too, like "Reply", "Forward", etc**

I have reverse engineered what strange things Salesforce is doing for outbound emails:

1. A Task of `TaskSubtype` = 'Email' will be created
2. The `WhatId` of `Task` is pointing to the record from which I have sent the email
3. An `EmailMessage` will be created with it's `ActivityId` set to the Task-Id
4. Attachments will be stored as `ContentDocument` having `ContentDocumentsLink` to the `EmailMessage`, not to the Task

Now translating this recipe for inbound emails, my code should look something like this (which works fine, all but **one** line):

```
global class pfBCQuoteDocumentEmailService  implements Messaging.InboundEmailHandler {
    global Messaging.InboundEmailResult handleInboundEmail(Messaging.InboundEmail email, Messaging.InboundEnvelope envelope) {
        Messaging.InboundEmailResult result = new Messaging.InboundEmailresult();
        try {
            String                  tibisId     = email.Subject.substringAfter('_').substringBefore('_'); 
            pfBCQuote__c            quote       = (pfBCQuote__c)(xs.query(''
                + ' select * from pfBCQuote__c where pfBCTibisID__c = \''+tibisId+'\' ' 
            ).get(0));
            String                  closedLabel = (String)(xs.query(''
                + ' select * from TaskStatus where IsClosed = true limit 1 ' 
            ).get(0).get('ApiName'));

            Task                    createTask  = new Task(
                 TaskSubtype                    = 'Email'
                ,Subject                        = email.Subject + ' [EmailService]'
                ,ActivityDate                   = Date.today()
                ,Status                         = closedLabel
                ,WhatId                         = quote.Id
                ,Description                    = email.plainTextBody
            );
            insert createTask;
            EmailMessage            createEmail = new EmailMessage(
                 Subject                        = email.Subject + ' [EmailService]'
                // ,ActivityId                      = createTask.Id // NOT WRITABLE !
                ,Status                         = '1'
                ,CcAddress                      = xt.implode(',',email.ccAddresses)
                ,FromAddress                    = email.fromAddress
                ,FromName                       = email.fromName
                ,Headers                        = JSON.serialize( email.headers )
                ,HtmlBody                       = email.htmlBody
                ,TextBody                       = email.plainTextBody
                ,Incoming                       = true
                ,MessageDate                    = DateTime.now()

            );
            insert createEmail; 
            xt.logMail('pfBCQuoteDocumentEmailService.handleInboundEmail()',new Object[]{email,quote} );
        } catch(Exception e) {
            xt.logMail('ERROR :: pfBCQuoteDocumentEmailService.handleInboundEmail()',e);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

**Sidenotes to the code (irrelevant to my main question)**

- xs.query() just selects stuff with * without all the hassel
- pfBCQuote__c is the object to which I want to add the received Email
- pfBCTibisID__c is a field on the record matching to a fragment of the incoming emails subject to get the appropriate record on which the email should be put in the activity tab.
- xt.logMail() is simply send debug-emails to myself as alternative to creep through the logs - just ignore it.

**What does NOT work is setting the ActivityId on the EmailMessage.**

> Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error:
>   INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_OR_READONLY, You cannot edit this field:
>   [ActivityId]

**Now my question is: What is the BEST way to store incoming emails to work in the Activity-Tab best?**

- Should I only create the Task and go without the EmailMessage?
- Is there a different way to link Task and EmailMessage?
- How should I put received Attachments?
- is there a way to do that more out-of-the-box with less reverse-engineering and try-to-replicate-what-salesforce-does?
- is there specific documentation how Salesforce stores Emails on Record-Level?
- Has anyone done something similar and is willing to share some code-snippets or conceptual approaches?
- How would you store attachments? `ContentDocument`+Version or `Attachment`

**What is working so far**

- Activity gets create with the right icon

[image]

**What is still missing**

- fancy Reply, Forward stuff
- handling of email attachments

**UPDATE**

I did some more research and found insufficient documentation - but at least a bit: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_emailmessage.htm

Doing like my reverse-engineered recipe seems just to be right:

> `ActivityId`
>
> Type reference
>
> Properties **Create**, Filter, Group, Nillable, Sort
>
> ID of the activity that is associated with the email. Usually
>   represents an open task that is created for the case owner when a new
>   unread email message is received. ActivityId can only be specified for
>   emails on cases. It’s auto-created for other entities.

It looks like another castration of Apex compared to the API. Using the API the field `ActivityId` is usable on insert - only not updateable. Using APEX we get a punch and cannot even set it once on insert. We just can't set it at all. Hence we can't use it at all :-( Why that?

Also I think the only appropriate way to deal attachments is via `ContentVersion` with a link via something like `Messaging.EmailFileAttachment`. Going with the old `Attachment` just seems **totally wrong**. But I'm not sure on how to glue my EmailMessage to the ContentVersion. I will investigate that further, also happy to get hints from you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From what I understand, You don't need to create a task to insert an EmailMessage. Email message has `relatedToId` field which you can use to directly link it to any desired record. As relatedToId is polymorphic like ParentId for Attachments, you should be fine.

Source: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.212.0.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_emailmessage.htm

1. **fancy Reply, Forward stuff** : This can be easily handled by creating a record of `EmailMessageRelation`.  It can only be created if email-to-case is enabled in your org.

   SRC : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.212.0.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_emailmessage.htm

SRC: [Send and Receive Email in Account,Lead,Opportunity,Quotes,Contact and maintain email loop](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/203820/send-and-receive-email-in-account-lead-opportunity-quotes-contact-and-maintain-e/204199#204199)

**2. handling of email attachments :** I don't fancy using standard Salesforce Attachment. Because attaching them to different records means cloning it and you cant' controll access(Determined by parent always).
   Creating a content version and linking it to email message looks the best solution to me. I recently created a utility method for linking email attachments to emailMessage as content document , you can refer it.

```
    public void 
    createContentDocumentLinks(Messaging.InboundEmail.BinaryAttachment[] binAttachList,
        Id insertedEmailMessageId) {
    List<ContentVersion>cvList = new List<ContentVersion>();
    List<ContentDocumentLink> cdlList = new List<ContentDocumentLink>();
    if (binAttachList == null) {
        return null;
    }
    for (Messaging.InboundEmail.BinaryAttachment binAttach : binAttachList) {
        ContentVersion testContentInsert = new ContentVersion();
        testContentInsert.Title = binAttach.fileName;
        testContentInsert.VersionData = binAttach.body;
        testContentInsert.PathOnClient = '/' + binAttach.fileName ;
        cvList.add(testContentInsert);

    }
    insert cvList;
    cvList = [select id, ContentDocumentId from ContentVersion WHERE Id in :cvList];
    for (ContentVersion cv : cvList) {

        ContentDocumentLink cl = new ContentDocumentLink();
        cl.ContentDocumentId = cv.ContentDocumentId;
        cl.LinkedEntityId = insertedEmailMessageId;
        cl.ShareType = 'V';
        cl.Visibility = 'AllUsers';
        cdlList.add(cl);


    }
    insert cdlList;


    }
```

Comment: RelatedToId works just fine! Under the hood the outcome is a bit different as Salesforce is storing Emails, because it's without this magic-Task as described above. But on the UI it looks almost the same and there is the same functionality (including Reply, Forward, etc)

Comment: Hi Pranay, thanks again for your answer. Basically I'm using your pattern here https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/224690/how-to-create-an-emailmessage-record-with-dml-having-hasattachment-to-be-true but currently I can't get the HasAttachment field right. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
                 EmailMessage em = new EmailMessage();
                 em.Incoming = true;
                 em.FromAddress = 'test@gmail.com';
                 em.FromName = 'test';
                 em.HtmlBody = 'test body';
                 em.Subject  = 'test subject';
                 em.ToAddress = em.BccAddress = 'to address';
                 em.status = '2';(for incoming email status 2 and outgoing email status 1)
                 em.RelatedToId = object.id;
                 insert em;
                 (The RelatedToId represents nonhuman objects such as accounts, 
                  opportunities, campaigns, cases, or custom objects. RelatedToIds are 
                  polymorphic. Polymorphic means a RelatedToId is equivalent to the ID 
                  of a related object.)
```