# How to Messaging.sendEmail() so that the email is properly shown on a record's activity tab in Lightning Experience?

Tags: apex, lightning-experience, tasks, singleemailmessage, send-email

This question is related to but different from [How to use an Apex Email Service to store emails on a record EXACTLY as Salesforce does?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/224492/how-to-use-an-apex-email-service-to-store-emails-on-a-record-exactly-as-salesfor)

I want to send an Email using `Messaging.sendEmail()`

This Email should appear at the appropriate place in the activity tab, exactly as salesforce is placing them when sending using the LEX UI:

[image]

My current (halfway working) code looks like this

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage    m = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    m.setToAddresses(           new String[]{'heim@elastify.eu'} );
    m.setSubject(               'test' );
    m.setHtmlBody(              'whatever' );
ContentVersion                  cv = new ContentVersion();
    cv.Title                    = email.Subject+'.pdf';
    cv.PathOnClient             = cv.Title;
    cv.VersionData              = anyPdfBlobDoesNotMatterWhat;
    cv.SharingOption            = 'A'; // A : 'Allowed'
insert cv;
cv                              = [ SELECT Id, FileType, Title, ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion WHERE Id =: cv.Id];
ContentDocumentLink             cdl                     = new ContentDocumentLink();
    cdl.ContentDocumentId       = cv.ContentDocumentId;
    cdl.LinkedEntityId          = t.Id;
    cdl.ShareType               = 'I'; // I : 'Inferred' = The user’s permission is determined by the related record.
insert cdl;
Messaging.EmailFileAttachment   efa = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
    efa.setFileName(cv.Title);
    efa.setBody( pdfBlob );
    efa.setContentType('application/pdf'); // does not work: (cv.FileType);
    efa.setInline(false);
m.setFileAttachments( new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[]{ efa });

if(!(Test.isRunningTest())) {
    Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { m });
}
```

Only that I can not link the sent email to a given Record, lets say there is an SObject `MyObject__c record`, queried with a given Id. The id is available as `record.Id`

**How can I connect `record` or `record.Id` to the email sent above??**

Assuming that again like [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/224492/how-to-use-an-apex-email-service-to-store-emails-on-a-record-exactly-as-salesfor) we have to magically and undocumented glue that together using junction task, following a recipe like:

1. Create a wrapper/junction Task
2. Link the EmailMessage somehow via ActivityId to the wrapper Task

Only that seems not to be possible. Again.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To link the task/email to a record, use setWhatId (e.g. `m.setWhatId(record.Id);`). This should link the email automatically.

Sample Code:

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage m = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
m.setWhatId([select id from account where name = 'Test Account' limit 1].id);
m.setSubject('test');
m.settoaddresses(new string[] { '<set-valid-email-here>' });
m.setsaveasactivity(true);
m.setplaintextbody('Hello world');
messaging.sendemail(new messaging.email[] { m });
```

---

Account details:

[image: Sample of Email Details]