# How to create an EmailMessage record with DML having HasAttachment to be 'true'?

Tags: apex, email, contentdocument, emailmessage, contentdocumentlink

I'm creating EmailMessage records via DML

```
EmailMessage createWhatEmail = new EmailMessage(
     Subject                = 'test'
    ,Status                 = '3'
    ,ToAddress              = 'heim@elastify.eu'
    ,FromAddress            = UserInfo.getUserEmail()
    ,FromName               = UserInfo.getFirstName()+' - '+UserInfo.getLastName()
    ,HtmlBody               = 'a body'
    ,Incoming               = false
    ,MessageDate            = DateTime.now()
    ,RelatedToId            = taskWhatId
    // ,HasAttachment       = true // not possible: Read-Only!
);
insert createWhatEmail;
```

The attachments I'm assigning like this:

```
for(ContentVersion cv : attachmentCVs) {
    ContentDocumentLink cdl = new ContentDocumentLink(
         ContentDocumentId  = cv.ContentDocumentId
        ,LinkedEntityId     = createWhatEmail.Id
        ,ShareType          = 'V' 
    );
    attachmentCDLs.add( cdl );
}
```

But the result is not flawless:

[image]

The **attachment is shown** correctly under the Attachments related list. But  the non-writable `HasAttachment` field is `false`. Hence the paper-clip indicating the attachment isn't show in the Activity Tab under LEX.

Does anyone know a way to make this right?

The result should look more like this:

[image]

Comment: I somehow feel this is related to this [issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000mptaQAA). It though says it was fixed in Summer '18.

Comment: @JayantDas could be related, but also could be an other bug. Or a feature. Or I'm doing something wrong. I would love to learn more about this. Only thing I can say: the behavior described above is reproducible on all of the org I'm working on.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 8):

I spent close to 4 hours on this and figured it out. The key thing is to populate `Attachment.ParentId` with `EmailMessage` Id.

Here is the sample code:

```
EmailMessage emailMessage = new EmailMessage();
emailMessage.status = '3'; // email was sent
emailMessage.relatedToId = '001XXXXXXXXXXX'; 
emailMessage.fromAddress = 'billing@acme.com'; // from address
emailMessage.fromName = 'Billing Department'; // from name
emailMessage.toAddress = 'johnSmith@example.com';
emailMessage.Subject = 'Hello';

emailMessage.HtmlBody = 'Hello World';
insert emailMessage;

Attachment obj = new Attachment();
obj.Body = Blob.valueOf('Test Blob');
obj.ParentId = emailMessage.Id;
obj.Name = 'Dummy.pdf';
obj.ContentType = 'application/pdf';
insert obj;

System.debug([SELECT Id,HasAttachment FROM EmailMessage WHERE Id =: emailMessage.Id]);
```

Comment: To future readers, you don't need to create a dummy VF page. You can simply use: `Blob bodyBlob = Blob.valueOf('Test Blob'); ` To create dummy Blob data.

Comment: @user2018 Thank you. Updated my answer.